# Why is that the radical ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

In my lecture notes we have the following:

**Definition:** $f, g \in \mathbb{C}[x, y]$

$f \sim g \Leftrightarrow \exists c \in \mathbb{C}, c \neq 0$ such that $g=cf$

**Example:** If $f \sim g \Rightarrow V(f)=V(g)$. The converse doesn't stand.

But from Nullstellensatz we have that $$V(f)=V(g) \Leftrightarrow Rad(\langle f\rangle )=Rad(\langle g\rangle )$$

If $$f=f_1^{a_1} \cdot f_2^{a_2} \cdot \dots \cdot f_s^{a_s}$$ where $f_i$ are irreducible polynomials of $\mathbb{C}[x, y]$ then, $$Rad(\langle f\rangle )=\langle f_1, f_2, \dots , f_s \rangle$$

So $V(f)=V(g)$ $\Leftrightarrow $ the irreducible factors of $f$ and $g$ are the same.

$$$$

Can you explain to me why it stands that $$Rad(\langle f\rangle )=\langle f_1, f_2, \dots , f_s \rangle$$

Comment: That doesn't look right. I think you want to say that $\operatorname{rad}((f)) = (f_1 \cdots f_s)$. This follows from unique factorization. [Of course, you want to say that the $f_i$ are distinct.]

Comment: How can we show this? How does this follow from unique factorization? @Hoot

Answer (score 1):

> Can you explain to me why it stands that $$Rad(\langle f\rangle )=\langle f_1, f_2, \dots , f_s \rangle$$

This is false. What is true is that  $$Rad(\langle f\rangle )=\langle f_1f_2 \dots  f_s \rangle$$ when you assume in addition that the $f_i$ are not associated elements ('associated'  is the $\sim$ realation you recalled).

To see this note that if $h^n \in \langle f \rangle$,  then $f \mid h^n$ and so $f_i \mid h^n$ for each $i$. Since $f_i$ is irreducible and thus a prime element, it follows that $f_i \mid h$ for each $i$ and further, again using 'prime', that $f_1 \dots f_s \mid h$ so the radical ideal is contained in $\langle f_1f_2 \dots  f_s \rangle$.

Conversely let $a$ be the maximum of the $a_i$, then $f \mid (f_1f_2 \dots  f_s)^a$ showing that $f_1f_2 \dots  f_s$ is in the radical ideal.